Error al hacer push en GIT
He creado un repositorio en GitHub para poder subir mi proyecto de Netbeans.
En dicho IDE, he inicializado el repositorio y me ha permitido hacer el commit inicial, despues para hacer push introduzco correctamente el enlace del repo, mi nombre de usuario y token, especifico la rama y le doy a Finish, pero me aparece el siguiente error:

Git command returned with the following error:  COMMIT
[231764387cb732b2e542ee41d221e2179d457945] does not exist.

Y no pushea absolutamente nada.

Esto no tiene que ver con netbeans en si mismo, tiene que ver con el orden que estás usando los comandos, y que cosas quieres añadir al commit. Sabes como va el tema para hacer push en git ?

Aquí dicen que basta con reiniciar el Netbeans. Aunque también se me ocurre que el error ocurre porque los repositorios no están sincronizados. Pero primero intenta reiniciando el IDE.
